# Capturing and replicating IR signals, how to tell frequencies?

Tags: frequency, infrared

I want to capture and replicate IR signals of various electronics.  There are various guides out there.  However, I realize that there are various carrier frequencies, which I dont see discussed.  How do I know what frequency of my target electronics in order to buy the right IR receiver and transmitter?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You buy a common phototransistor that does not depend on a particular modulation scheme, add a biasing resistor, and observe the signal on an oscilloscope.

Comment: Is there any guide or tutorial with circuitry that you can point me to?

Comment: Your favorite internet search engine is your friend now, try using keywords like "phototransistor" "circuit" "biasing".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a universal remote control, you can't really make any assumptions about the frequency required.

A simple infrared photodiode will accept any frequency.  It's then up to you to amplify the tiny signal they produce, digitise it and store it in memory.